# Clear tables with foreign keys + Propel

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, propel

I have a mysql database with some tables in it. An example of two tables:

> TABLE "**dogtoilets**"
>     - type
>     - location_id (FK)
>
> TABLE "**locations**"
>     - id
>     - latitude
>     - longitude

My question is how can I clear the table "dogtoilets and also clear the locations in my locations table that are linked to dogtoilets?

Tried this but locations don't delete ...

```
$dogtoilets = DogToiletQuery::create()
        ->leftJoinWith('Dogtoilet.Location')
        ->find();
    $dogtoilets->delete();
```

Comment: You need a primary key `location_id` in table **locations** to map with foreign key in **dogtoilets**

Comment: I have a PK in my locations table!

Comment: Have a look [at how the node `<foreign-key>` can be define](http://propelorm.org/reference/schema.html#foreign-key-element). Specially the attribute `onDelete`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this help:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#CASCADE

Cascade will only work when you delete row in "**locations**", it automatically delete related rows in "**dogtoilets**"

In this case you should delete manually using your code.

Comment: And how can I set this in propel? (In my xml schema?)

Comment: @nielsv `<foreign-key foreignTable="locations" onDelete="CASCADE">`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the foreign key constraints :

```
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

It will delete all referenced objects linked with a FK.

Comment: And how can I set this in propel? (In my xml schema?)